# How can I cast media TO an android device?

Tags: android, streaming, tablet, miracast

My setup consists of a windows PC and a few nearby android tablets.  They are all connected to the same LAN via Wi-Fi, and I have full control over these devices.

Here's the situation:

Sometimes I'll be watching a video, say YouTube, or Hulu, or whatnot, on the Windows PC.  This is typically through a traditional web browser, usually Microsoft Edge (though I'm flexible on this point if necessary).  I may then decide that I need the PC for other purposes, perhaps work or a full-screen application of some variety.

What I'd like to do at this point is be able to click somewhere in my browser and "send to Tablet".  Some means to automatically open a browser (or even more awesome would be the appropriate dedicated app) on the tablet, and start playing the content where I left off on the PC.

I can do this in the other direction very easily via the "cast" mechanism that the Android tablets provide.  But I can't figure out how to "cast" TO the Android tablet, rather than FROM the Android tablet.

I usually wind up copy-pasting the link from my browser window into some kind of messaging program, send a message to myself, move over to the tablet, open messenger, and click the link, but this feels oddly tedious.  Am I missing an easier way to achieve this result?

Comment: Have you tried to install a cast receiver app on the tablet?

Comment: Can you suggest one?  I haven't been able to find a cast receiver app, only cast transmitter apps.